# Nextjs - first level dynamic routing for many pages each of which has children

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing, dynamic-routing

Nextjs - first level dynamic routing for many pages each of which has children

I have a NextJS 12.2/React 18 app linked to a CMS, where users can set up their custom page structure, content & theme.

- In the front-end, there will be some API calls to get the app
  settings and configuration including the page hierarchy.
- The default six top-level page names are homepage, content, events,
  user, search and blog.
- We can think of these six pages as types, so we have six different
  types, and users can change the names of these types but not the type
  itself. And as you may expect, changing the names will change the URL
  segment accordingly.
- Four of those six types can have child-page(s), multi-level (nested).
  Here are some examples of what the default app's URLs can look like:

  ```
       mydomain.com/homepage 
       mydomain.com/content/
       mydomain.com/events/by-location/[locationID]
       mydomain.com/events/[eventID]
       mydomain.com/events/by-category/[catLevelOne]
       mydomain.com/user/profile 
       mydomain.com/blog/[postID]
       mydomain.com/search?term=searchterm
       mydomain.com/contact-us
  ```
- Notice: there is also a static page "contact-us" which is not connected to the CMS.
- To achieve this model within the NextJS methodology of routing, the app file structure should look like this (if it is allowed):

```
    pages
    ├── [blog]
    │   ├── [postID].js
    │   └── index.js
    ├── [content]
    │   ├── [levelOne]
    │   │   ├── [levelTwo]
    │   │   │   ├── [levelThree]
    │   │   │   │   └── index.js
    │   │   │   └── index.js
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   └── index.js
    ├── [events]
    │   ├── by-category
    │   │   ├── [catLevelOne]
    │   │   │   ├── [catLevelTwo]
    │   │   │   │   └── index.js
    │   │   │   └── index.js
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── by-location
    │   │   ├── [location]
    │   │   │   ├── [locationID].js
    │   │   │   └── index.js
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── [eventID].js
    ├── [user]
    │   ├── account.js
    │   ├── emailverification.js
    │   ├── password.js
    │   └── register.js
    ├── search.js
    └── homepage.js
```

- And this is not possible as we cannot have two folders with brackets on the same level!
- If I hard-code file names of the top-level pages, they worked just fine, however, the problem starts when the user changes their default names (homepage, content, events, ...etc) into something else, NextJS then will have no idea what the pages' structure is yet so it through a 404 not found straight away, as getting the file structure from the API will take few seconds to fetch.

**What I have tried:**

1. middleware: it turned out that we can't fetch data inside middleware.js and if we did, there will be tens of API calls each time the route changes.
2. I tried the one dynamic route method, so I fetched the data server-side inside a [wildcard].js file and then based on the data that came back I rewrote the URL to route the requests in the right direction based on the pages types, which is basically the hard-coded page names. That works smoothly but for the top pages not for their children.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to follow that URL structure? Could you not have, for instance, `mydomain.com/events/<event-name>/by-location/<event-location>/<location-id>`, where you add `events` or `content` or `user` at the beginning of the path? This would solve the problem of having multiple dynamic routes at the same level.

Comment: unfortunately yes, that structure needs to be followed, note that someone would maybe name that in your example "events" while another user will name it "news" and a third one give it "occasions"...etc all should point to the same [page]...hence the question in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party but in case someone still needs this, I think you were very close. Using [shallow-routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) with your second approach should do the job. Basically add `[...wildcard].js` and

> based on the data that comes back, rewrote the URL to route the requests in the right direction based on the pages types

A good idea would be to do this in the [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) function since you can make requests there, it will be faster, and you don't have to worry about any glitch when the page loads.

Also in case anyone has any doubts:
Of course we can't have `two folders with brackets on the same level` because if you have `[id1]` and `[id2]` how will the nextJS know what `mydomain.com/1234` should be? There is now way to tell if `1234` is `id1` or `id2`.

I think the last part is probably obvious, but still... In case anyone wonders.

Comment: Great answer, and got me to where I needed to be - thanks. Just a note that I believe its called "catch all" (https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)